# Добавить в базу данных выбранные чекбоксы

Tags: php, html, form, checkbox

Нужно добавить выбранные цвета (в одной записи) в таблицу users в colors, я делаю что-то подобное, но не работает

```
 <?php
 $aDoor = $_POST['formDoor'];
 if(empty($aDoor))
  {
echo("Вы ничего не выбрали.");
   }
  else
    {
    $N = count($aDoor);
     echo("Вы выбрали $N цвет(а/ов)");
     for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
     {
     $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (colors) VALUES('$aDoor[$i]')");
      }
      }
      ?>  


  <form action="colors.php" method="post">

  <input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Красный" />Красный<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Синий"/>Синий<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Желтый" />Жёлтый<br />

   <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так:

```php
<?php
$aDoor = $_POST['formDoor'];
if(empty($aDoor))
{
    echo("Вы ничего не выбрали.");
}
else
{
    $val = implode("', '", $aDoor);
    $N = count($aDoor);
    echo("Вы выбрали $N цвет(а/ов)");
    $result = "INSERT INTO `users` (colors) VALUES('$val')";
    //Дальше отправляем запрос mysql.
    print_r($result);


}
?>


<form action="" method="post">

    <input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Красный" />Красный<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Оранжевый"/>Оранжевый<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Желтый" />Жёлтый<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Зелёный" />Зелёный<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Голубой" />Голубой<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Синий" />Синий<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Фиолетовый" />Фиолетовый<br />

    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Поможет такой код? Подправьте без ошибок если подойдёт

```
  <form action="#" method="post">

  <input type="checkbox" name="doorRed" value="Красный" />Красный<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="doorBlue" value="Синий"/>Синий<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="doorYellow" value="Желтый" />Жёлтый<br />

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить" />
    </form> 

<?php
$count = 0;
if($_POST['submit']) {
    if(!empty($_POST['doorRed'])) 
    {
        $red = $_POST['doorRed'];
        $count++;
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['doorBlue'])) {
        $blue = $_POST['doorBlue'];
        $count++;
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['doorYellow'])) {
        $yellow = $_POST['doorYellow'];
        $count++;
    }
}
if($count == 1)
echo 'Вы выбрали ' .$count. ' цвет';
if($count >= 2)
echo 'Вы выбрали ' .$count. ' цвета';

$mysqli_connect(host,login,pass,dataBase);
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (colors) VALUES('$red','$blue$','$yellow')";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

if($result)
{
    echo 'Данные занесены в БД';
}

?>
```

Comment: А проще сделать нельзя? Конечно, если всего два цвета, тогда можно и так. Но, если их 30 и более?

Comment: Ответом на вопрос можно сделать это. если 30 цветов, то конечно другой вариант надо. С массивами из формы не сталкивался